# My React JS Development Server is not loading, I'm getting these errors while adding "react-showdown dependency"

Tags: reactjs, package, dependencies, package.json

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at handleParseError (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
at runSyncOrAsync (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
at Array. (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
at Storage.finished (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at D:\NoteApp in ReactJS\my-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.17.0

I tried to install React-showdown dependency ended up getting these errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.